# My parents are going to split up because of me how do i stop this?

Tags: conflict, step-parents

I know I'm not a parent or anything bit I dont know where else would be a good place to ask this

I'm a younger than 16 girl (dont want to share my real age) and my parents are going through some trouble.

For a bit of background my mum died when I was super young and my dad got with my new step mum 5 years ago after a bad relationship ended and we were living with my gran.

So for the past like 4 years we have being living with step mum and her daughter and for those last years I've had problems with something I don't want to go into online but it's had a tole on my parents, yesterday I done something so stupid and so petty that I regret and ne and my step mum had an argument about it today. She said she's done with everything and with us saying she's had it with dealing with me and then my dad because he's upset about the situation he gets cranky and stuff.

I'm aware that's a horrible summary of the situation but I don't want to put too much of our personal life out there.

I don't want my new family to be split up my dad will probably hate me and be heartbroken I don't want any of this but I don't know how to stop it. I don't know if she was just saying she was going to leave in the argument or actually thinking about it but I don't want to just assume it was a heat of the moment thing. Please can someone help me stop them from splitting up and stopping any future problems that are caused by me in the future?

Comment: Please understand that divorces happen between two adults, not between adults and children. It’s perfectly ok to talk with your parents about your fears and feelings (including remorse), but ultimately it’s their decision.